# I'm using coding keys in swift but it's giving this error

Tags: swift, enums, codable

I need to read a CSV file placed in my bundle , when i decode each row it has different column names , i want to map that on my custom object structure, for that i was trying to use coding keys but it's not working , kindly have a look and let me know if i need to change anything

[image: In this image an error is showing that Multiple Enum raw types , i dont know what's that mean! thanks if anyone can help]

Comment: What you mean is 'CodingKey'

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] as text, using proper code formatting and not as a screenshot.

Comment: You have put an extra `s` in `CodingKeys`

Comment: coding keys are used for mapping that if a json/csv row has some weird name then you can use coding keys to map that name into some meaningful name

Comment: issue is resolved, the coding keys written in green color. Autocompleted using my own codingkeys name and mixed with original codingkey provided by apple , that's why it was showing error . the first comment below showed that there is an extra S in the name when i removed that it started working fine. Thanks to all who tried to guide me

Comment: This Question should not be downvoted, Everyone faces small issues and makes mistakes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to replace with `CodingKey`

```
private  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
```

Comment: his CodingKeys Color is green. I think he has an enum with CodingKeys name. like this : enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
{
    case data = "data"
}

Comment: Typo problems are a reason to *close* the question as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

There is no protocol named `CodingKeys`, but `CodingKey`

Answer (score 1):

If you subclass `CSVModel` from `NSObject, Decoable` you don't need to assign with `CodingKeys`

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear. please show me your "CodingKeys" code.
I think your "CodingKeys" has String and CodingKey. and you must delete "String" from "codingKeys". this error telling you are using String again.